# Thowing custom AuthenticationException inside UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter's attemptAuthentication not working when reading in AuthEntryPoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**Custom `AuthenticationException`**:

```
public class UnauthorizedException extends AuthenticationException {

    public UnauthorizedException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public UnauthorizedException(final String message, final Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

**Custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`'s `attemptFunction()`**:

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            UserRequestDto userRequestDto = mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), UserRequestDto.class);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userRequestDto.getUsername(), userRequestDto.getPassword()
            );
            return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            throw new ServerErrorException(this.accessor.getMessage("server.error"));
        } catch (DisabledException disabledException) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(this.accessor.getMessage("user.disabledAccount"));
        } catch (LockedException lockedException) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(this.accessor.getMessage("user.lockedAccount"));
        } catch (BadCredentialsException | EntryNotFoundException badCredentialsException) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(this.accessor.getMessage("user.incorrectCredentials"));
        } catch (AuthenticationException entryNotFoundException) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(this.accessor.getMessage("user.incorrectCredentials"));
        }
    }
```

**Custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint`**:

```
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        System.out.println(authException.getMessage());

        int UNAUTHORIZED = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value();
        response.setStatus(UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        Response<Integer> responseBuild = Response.build(String.valueOf(UNAUTHORIZED), true);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), responseBuild);
    }
```

The last catch block inside `attemptAuthentication()` method throws custom `AuthenticationException` with custom message ("Incorrect username or password"), but when printing `AuthenticationException`'s message in `AuthenticationEntryPoint`'s `commence()` method, it prints out "**InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource**" (both when given username does and does not exist in the database).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example for the issue you're having. Without seeing all the relevant configuration it's hard to tell what's the problem. Also, try setting the logging level of `org.springframework.security` to `trace` and see what's going on when you send your request.

Comment: I suspect that your authentication filter is not being called as you expect. This can be the result of a misconfiguration of the filters that causes your filter to be in the wrong order and it doesn't get a stab at authentication. Try placing a break point inside your `attemptAuthentication` method and see if it's being invoked. If not, check your spring security configuration.

Comment: Did you debug your code? Because it seems that it should throw AccessDeniedException which is not catched by your custom filter. 
Please, show your configuration for routes and get authException class in commence() method.